# Determine previous color used in PS1

Tags: bash, prompt

**Right now my PS1 looks like this**
[image]

I want that "▸" background color to change depending on the color of the last section. So, if I wasn't in a git repo, it should be blue but when I'm in a git repo, yellow.

Here is what my PS1 looks like in my `.bash_profile`

```
# git info on prompt
function __git_info() {
  local -r SYMBOL_GIT_BRANCH="⑂";
  local -r SYMBOL_GIT_MODIFIED="*";
  local -r SYMBOL_GIT_PUSH="↑";
  local -r SYMBOL_GIT_PULL="↓";

  hash git 2>/dev/null || return 0; # git not found

  # current branch reference
  local ref=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2>/dev/null);

  # if it's not a normal branch name, get tag name or short unique hash
  [[ -z "$ref" ]] && ref=$(git describe --tags --always 2>/dev/null);
  [[ -n "$ref" ]] || return 0;  #not a git repo

  local following; # ahead/behind count
  local modified; # whether something has been modified locally
  local extras; # additional info
  local status; # status of the repo
  local untracked; # whether or not there are untracked files
  local staged; # whether or not there are staged files

  status=$(git status 2>&1 | tee);
  untracked=$(printf "%s" "$status" 2> /dev/null | grep -m 1 "Untracked files" &> /dev/null; printf "%s" "$?");
  staged=$(printf "%s" "$status" 2> /dev/null | grep -m 1 "Changes to be committed" &> /dev/null; printf "%s" "$?");

  [[ "${untracked}" == "0" ]] && extras+="?";
  [[ "${staged}" == "0" ]] && extras+="+";

  # scan first two lines of output from `git status`
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^## ]]; then #header line
      [[ $line =~ ahead\ ([0-9]+) ]] && following+="$SYMBOL_GIT_PUSH${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
      [[ $line =~ behind\ ([0-9]+) ]] && following+="$SYMBOL_GIT_PULL${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    else #branch is modified if output contains more lines after the header
      modified=" $SYMBOL_GIT_MODIFIED";
      break;
    fi;
  done < <(git status --porcelain --branch 2>/dev/null);

  # print the git branch segment without a trailing newline
  printf "%s" " [$SYMBOL_GIT_BRANCH$following $ref$modified$extras] ";
}

## Prompt customizations ##
function __host() {
  printf '\[\e[30;102m\] \h \[\e[0m\]';
}

function __dir() {
  printf '\[\e[1;97;44m\] \w \[\e[0m\]';
}

function __git_status() {
  printf "\[\e[30;43m\]\$(__git_info)\[\e[0m\]";
}

function __arrow() {
  printf '\[\e[1;97;44m\] ▸ \[\e[0m\]';
}

export PS1="$(__host)$(__dir)$(__git_status)$(__arrow) "
```

Anyone got any ideas how this can be accomplished? I tried setting global vars, but the PS1 is using subshells so that won't work.

Comment: Can't you just remove `\[\e[0m\]` from the end of `__git_status()` and `\[\e[1;97;44m\]` from the beginning of `__arrow()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your `__git_info` function returns a status, so why not use it?  (Make sure you have it return NON-zero when you ARE is a git repo.)  Don't reset the colors in the function, but allow them to remain as they are and reset them after the arrow:

```
function __dir() {
  printf '\[\e[1;97;44m\] \w ';
}

function __git_status() {
  local info=$(__git_info)
  [ $? -ne 0 ] && printf "\[\e[30;43m\]$info";
}

function __arrow() {
  printf ' ▸ \[\e[0m\]';
}

export PS1="$(__host)$(__dir)$(__git_status)$(__arrow) "
```

Comment: Adding a `return 1;` to `__git_info` doesn't seem to return a non-zero.

Comment: This would also make the `__git_status` text bolded, which I didn't want to do.

Comment: Turn off the bolding at the end of `__dir` with `\e[21m`.

Comment: How do I disable just the bolding without escaping all the styles?

I still can't get the exit status of `__gif_info` to be anything other than `0`.

Comment: Sorry -- just edited comment!  Here is a good list: https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Comment: In `__git_info`, change the `return 0` statements to `return 1`, then change the conditional in `__git_status` to `[ $? -eq 0 ]`.

Comment: That still won't work. It's returning 0 regardless of the dir being a repo or not.

Comment: You have a `return 1`, and it's returning 0?

Comment: `local` masks the return value of the command substitution. You have to do `local var; var=$(somecommand)` (see https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155)

Comment: Correct. No matter what return code I put anywhere in that function, `echo $?` always yields `0`.

Comment: Thanks, @BenjaminW.  Learn something new every day!

Comment: Okay so that's working now. Last problem is that if I go into a git repo, the git status isn't shown unless I `touch ~.bash_profile`. When cd into a non-git repo from there, the git info stays in the prompt.

Comment: Try putting the PS1 variable in single quotes, not double: `export PS1='$(__host)$(__dir)$(__git_status)$(__arrow) '`

Comment: That breaks all the escaping.

Comment: With single quotes, you should not need escaping.

Comment: The issue seems that the return value from `__gif_info` isn't being updated between commands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177111/discussion-between-jack-and-nxt3).